# Assert anonymous object equivalence

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, fluent-assertions

I'm sure i'm missing the obvious...

Say we have:

```cs
[Fact]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var a = new { SomeProp = "hello", AnotherProp = 9 };
    var b = new { SomeProp = "hello" };
    var c = new { AnotherProp = 9 };
    var d = new { SomeProp = "hello", AnotherProp = 9 };
}
```

What is the correct assertion to check that all of the properties match (e.g. `a` and `d` would return true, but all other combinations would return false?

At the moment, i'm doing equivalency checks, but have to do it in both directions? e.g.

```cs
    a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(d);
    d.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a);
```

Forgive me if this is clearly defined in the docs... I can't find it :/

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, `a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(d);` does exactly that.

Comment: That only checks that the properties of `d` have matching properties in `a`. But it doesn't check the other way around. Try it and you will find ` a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);` and ` a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(c);` also pass

Answer (score 0):

From the microsoft docs:

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are
> defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the
> properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
> all their properties are equal.

I am not sure about the specifics of .BeEquivalentTo but if it relies on the == operator, this does not guarantee equality for anonymous types.

If the anonymous objects have exactly the same structure (including order) and the same values you can use:

`Assert.True(a.equals(d))

Otherwise you must assert each property manually

```
Assert.IsEqual(a.name, d.name); 
Assert.IsEqual(a.AnotherProp, d.AnotherProp)
```

EDIT: You cannot use hash codes to guarantee equality of two dispret objects. See the following from the MS docs:

> Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However,
> the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object
> equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash
> codes

Comment: `Assert.IsEqual(a.getHashCode(), d.getHashCode())` - this will *not* work. Hashcodes are can be the same for different values (this is why you need to overwrite `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for use of a type in a Dictionary, BTW). For some discussion (there are lots on the internet), see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/164970).

Comment: Interesting, I do remember in the docs the following: "Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However, the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash codes". I misinterpreted the docs section I posted in my answer above and will edit appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, which should be self-explanatory from the name.

E.g. if you say "A should be equivalent to B", you are *not* saying that A is the same as B, nor are you saying that B is equivalent to A.